# Is FIPS mode on ECS Fargate Tasks in AWS GovCloud possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, fips, aws-fargate

Trying to figure out whether enabling FIPS 140-2 mode (`crypto.fips_enabled = 1`) on ECS Fargate Task in AWS GovCloud is at all possible?

[image: AWS Fargate on GovCloud is FedRAMP High Compliant]

The AWS ECS service shows up as a FedRAMP High compliant, so it would be easy to assume that all Fargate host machines are running in FIPS mode by default. However, when I ran a Fargate task and check for fips availability, it comes out as 0 (disabled).

Given that FIPS mode is a kernel feature, I am guessing is there still a way to turn it on? Or maybe there is a task config option that would let me run my container on a FIPS-enabled host?

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this long-languishing enhancement request, it does not appear possible now.

[[ECS] [request]: FIPS support for containers running in Fargate #659](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/659)

Comment: Thanks a lot @kmarsh ! I came across the same github issue as well, but given that I believe in miracles, didn't want to believe that the situation is in fact that bad :) Then consulted with a FedRAMP advisory agency, and they confirmed the same. Thank you for the answer! It's sad, though, that AWS can get FedRAMP approved while not obeying the rules. It's a typical case of double standards. For now, we'll stay away from Fargate and will use EC2-based ECS deployment on GovCloud.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, AWS has implemented a fix that enables FIPS 140-2 mode in Fargate containers. https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/04/amazon-ecs-aws-fargate-fips-140-2-govcloud-us-regions/

This, presumably, only works in GovCloud, but it is worth trying on the commercial cloud as well.